# Substr Logic Function

Tags: php, substr

I want to ask about **substr()** function. I have a code like this:

```
<?php    
$word = 'diriku';
    $word2 = $word;
    //first condition
    if ( (substr($word,-3)=="kah") or (substr($word,-3)=="lah") or (substr($word,-3)=="pun") or (substr($word,-3)=="nya"))
{
    $word2 = substr($word,0,-3);
}
    //second condition
else if( (substr($word,-2)=="ku") or (substr($word,-2)=="mu") )
{
    $word2 = substr($word,-2);
}
    echo $word2;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $word;
?>
```

Result must be : **DIRI** but I don't know why result is **DIR**. My opinion is the **substr** is cut the word at first condition although it's true or false.

So anyone know how to logic compare substr function so if the first condition true, it pass the else, and if cond is false, it continue to else, not always true.

Sorry for this mess explanation.. I don't know how to describe it clearly.

Comment: substr($word,-3) is 'iku'.. what are u trying to achieve here? are you trying to get the first 4 character of 'diriku'?

Comment: Nope, the explanation for my code is, it check the word, if it's contain 'kah', 'lah', 'pun', 'nya' at the last of the word/variable. Then it check again if it's have 'ku' or 'mu' at the last word. that's why the variable $word could be any words...

Comment: Ohh ok.. So right now, the word 'diriku' will be true on the second conditions, What do you want to process on both condition. I can see that you are assigning the $word2 to 'ku'.. Where 'diri' and 'dir' comes in?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if I set the word to a word that contain KAH it will be go to first condition, and if it contain KAH and KU, the word will go to both condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
        $word = 'songsangkukah';
        $word2 = $word;

        if ( (substr($word,-3)=="kah") or (substr($word,-3)=="lah") or (substr($word,-3)=="pun") or (substr($word,-3)=="nya"))
        {
           $word2 = substr($word, 0 , -3);
        }

        if((substr($word2,-2)=="ku")or(substr($word2,-2)=="mu"))
        {
            $word2 = substr($word2 , 0 , -2);
        }

        echo $word2;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $word;
    ?>
```

Here you go. the required output.

Comment: if i put the word "SONGSANGKUKAH" it must be SONGSANG

Comment: Nope, the explanation for my code is, it check the word, if it's contain 'kah', 'lah', 'pun', 'nya' at the last of the word/variable. Then it check again if it's have 'ku' or 'mu' at the last word. that's why the variable $word could be any words...

Comment: Great! I think its the best answer right now... Although when i put the word with songsangkukahku the result just songsangkukah... but its ok then... Thank You so much amit... Sorry bother You.. :D

Comment: actually to your requirment this is the answer if you want i can extend the functionality till there is a match in the string using preg_match.

Comment: It would be glad if You can make it as I need. Because I will create another condition for prefix word. :(

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
if ( (substr($word,-3)=="kah") or (substr($word,-3)=="lah") or (substr($word,-3)=="pun") or (substr($word,-3)=="nya"))
```

It seems that there is something wrong with your 3rd condition's )

Comment: Sorry, typo at stackoverflow... But my real code is like that. I've fixed that. But still not meet my answer

Answer (score -1):

Please check your code.

```
substr($word,-3=="pun"), 

// it should be 

(substr($word,-3)=="pun")
```